# Is there a standard/default function in javascript to return an array of attributes obtained from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

For example: if I have a list of records, like this:

```
[
  {
    'id' : 1,
    'name' : 'Renato'
  },
  {
    'id' : 2,
    'name' : 'John'
  }
]
```

and I want to get a list of `id`.

Comment: A [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) works perfectly here: `arr.map(item => item.id);` As @mhodges said, check out the suggested existing question.

Comment: 'var map = Array.prototype.map;' then `rec.map(function(currentValue,index,array){return currentValue.id})`